# SageMaker: How to manually run a Model Quality Monitor Job?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using the SageMaker SDK class `ModelQualityMonitor` to configure Model Evaluation over time.

The monitoring schedule does not support monthly or weekly time periods, in my case, the ground Truth period is longer than one month.

There's an example from [SageMaker Labs](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-mlops-workshop/blob/main/labs/05_model_monitor/05_model_monitor.ipynb) to run Data Quality Monitor manually, the idea seems to provide the input `constraints` and `statistics` with a `ProcessingInput`, but not sure how to do this.

Is it possible to run the SageMaker Model Quality Monitor job manually?

Answer (score 2):

Model Monitoring out of the box is currently accomplished by launching SageMaker Processing Jobs on a schedule with data capture input.

In the case of `ModelQualityMonitor`, two Processing Jobs are launched running two different containers. Namely, `sagemaker-model-monitor-groundtruth-merger` and `sagemaker-model-monitor-analyzer`

Manual execution of `ModelQualityMonitor` is currently not supported out of the box. That being said, similar to the example you shared which showcases how to manually trigger the  `DataQualityMonitor` Processing Job you could do the same for `ModelQualityMonitor`. For example you could look at launching the Processing Jobs and making sure the input/output is compliant. There is an extra level of complexity in the fact that there is the `sagemaker-model-monitor-groundtruth-merger` Processing Job that merges Data Capture to the Ground Truth data. The `sagemaker-model-monitor-analyzer` container then uses this merged data as input.

As such, the Data Capture format and folder structure, start and end times environment variables, etc. all need to be compliant.

To understand more on how `ModelQualityMonitor` is accomplished I suggest running [this](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker_model_monitor/model_quality/model_quality_churn_sdk.ipynb) example and investigating the Processing Jobs that are launched and their input/output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Marc K, based on you suggestions I've found out is possible to execute these jobs manually, basically if you use boto3 method `describe_processing_job` you can get the expected input and output parameters to run the `ground-truth-merger` and `monitor-analyzer` jobs.