# What inference can be made out of Baseline drift distance in data quality monitoring sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

[image]

How is the above distance calculated and can I set my own threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find information on how the distributions are compared here (see `distribution_constraints` in the table):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-monitor-byoc-constraints.html

You can change the threshold in the constraint file to what you would like.

The baseline computes baseline schema constraints and statistics for each feature using Deequ. If youwould like more details you can take a look at the implementation here:

https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/amazon/deequ/analyzers/Distance.scala

Comment: Thanks for the information, I do have some follow up questions 1. How can I solve the above baseline drifts without altering the threshold. 2. I'm running the monitoring job manually for data quality monitoring using _sagemaker-model-monitor-analyzer_ image; I tried replicating the same for model quality monitoring but it didn't work is there any other possible way to run the monitoring job manually for Model quality monitoring.

Comment: Kindly see this answer I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71960791/18272224